# Loading the content of html file into the div?

Tags: load, bind

First let me say I am a complete beginner when it comes to javascript. The problem I am dealing with is probably very simple to solve ;)
I am working on a web page where the text content is loaded from external html files into the div. This is done when a user clicks on a menu item. The following js code is loaded from a external file and works just fine:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(
            {
                showArrows:false,
                maintainPosition: false
            }
        ).data('jsp');              
        $('#start').bind(
            'click',
            function()
            {
                api.getContentPane().load(
                    'texts/start.html',
                    function()
                    {
                        api.reinitialise();
                    }
                );
                return false;
            }
        );  
        $('#nurkowanie').bind(
            'click',
            function()
            {
                api.getContentPane().load(
                    'texts/nurkowanie.html',
                    function()
                    {
                        api.reinitialise();
                    }
                );
                return false;
            }
        );
        $('#noclegi').bind(
            'click',
            function()
            {
                api.getContentPane().load(
                    'texts/noclegi.html',
                    function()
                    {
                        api.reinitialise();
                    }
                );
                return false;
            }
        );  
        $('#dojazd').bind(
            'click',
            function()
            {
                api.getContentPane().load(
                    'texts/start.html',
                    function()
                    {
                        api.reinitialise();
                    }
                );
                return false;
            }
        );  
        $('#galeria').bind(
            'click',
            function()
            {
                api.getContentPane().load(
                    'texts/galeria.html',
                    function()
                    {
                        api.reinitialise();
                    }
                );
                return false;
            }
        );  
        $('#linki').bind(
            'click',
            function()
            {
                api.getContentPane().load(
                    'texts/linki.html',
                    function()
                    {
                        api.reinitialise();
                    }
                );
                return false;
            }
        );  
        $('#kontakt').bind(
            'click',
            function()
            {
                api.getContentPane().load(
                    'texts/kontakt.html',
                    function()
                    {
                        api.reinitialise();
                    }
                );
                return false;
            }
        );  
    });
```

The problem is when the page loads for the first time. I want the div with class .scroll-pane to have the content from 'texts/start.html' loaded, the one which you would get when clicking on start link. Right now that div is blank. I tried to play with the code like:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.scroll-pane').load('texts/start.html');
    }
```

but I couldn't get it working.
Could someone give me few hints how to do that?

Thanks in advance
matt

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that what you're doing is the best way of doing this but you could use:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

So something like:

```
$.get("texts/start.html", function(data) {
  $(".scroll-pane').html(data);
})
```

So using jScrollPane you could do something like this for each click event:

```
$('#start').bind(
 'click',
 function()
 {
   $.get("texts/start.html", function(data) {
     api.getContentPane().html(data);
     api.reinitialise();
   });
   return false;
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Steve for a prompt reply! It's probably the worst way but it's the only way I know ;) I added your code to my js file and the content is loaded at the startup but my menu stoped working :( please have a look at http://grubyjaqb.website.pl/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the library you are using, but load() seems to be a function of the jScrollPane object. So you would need to call load on that rather than the plain div.

Try using this instead.

```
api.getContentPane().load(
                    'texts/start.html',
                    function()
                    {
                        api.reinitialise();
                    }
                );
```

Make sure it is after you have defined api.

Comment: Pleasure, if this is the answer could you mark is as the answer... thanks.